# Oracle - CHECK Constraint - Only allow column to be changed if value in different column is not null

Tags: oracle, constraints, check-constraints

So I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects (
ID  INTEGER  CONSTRAINT ProjPK PRIMARY KEY, 
Column1 VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ,
Column2 VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ,
Column3 INTEGER NULL ,
Column4 VARCHAR2(20) NULL ,
Column5 INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Column6 INTEGER NULL ,
Column7 DATE NULL
);
```

I need to come up with a CHECK-Constraint for Column7 that allows Column7 only to be changed to a different value if columns 4 and 6 are NOT NULL.

I would like to express that the column7 must be NULL if columns 4 or 6 are NULL, respectively only can be NOT NULL if columns 4 AND 6 are NOT NULL. I hope that makes sense.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A `CHECK` constraint can't do that because it pertains to the *current state* of the row, so it can't express the concept of "change". For that you'd need a trigger. You can of course express things like "the column must (not) be `NULL` if columns 4 and/or 6 are (not) `NULL`", but it's not clear if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Jeroin Mostert Thanks a lot for you comment! I would like to express that the column7 must be NULL if columns 4 or 6 are NULL, respectively only can be NOT NULL if columns 4 AND 6 are NOT NULL. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That's definitely within the purview of a `CHECK` constraint. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Oracle to write the constraint elegantly, but I'm hoping someone else does. A trigger is not required for this, in any case.

Comment: @f10aty pls learn what is a *minimal* example. If you have a question concerning three columns **do not** show a table with **seven** columns. It can confuse the answers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert congrat - I apreciate your style of *commenting*, I learned two new words today (pertain, purview) even not being on the site *English Language Lerners*;)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: Well that's actually not such a good thing, the comments should be accessible to a wide audience so I certainly don't *intentionally* use fancy language that people need to run to a dictionary for. But I have to focus to not be fancy. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple *check constraint* that defines your restriction

```
alter table projects add CONSTRAINT check_null 
CHECK ( (column4 is  null and column6 is null and column7 is null) or 
        (column4 is not null and column6 is not null and column7 is not null) );
```

**Some Test**

Fails as column7 defined and columns 4,6 not

```
 INSERT INTO projects (id, column1, column7)  VALUES (1, 'fail', SYSDATE);
 --ORA-02290: check constraint (xxx.CHECK_NULL) violated
```

OK as all columns  are `NULL`

```
  INSERT INTO projects (id, column1, column7)  VALUES (1, 'OK', null);
-- 1 row inserted.
```

.. or all defined.

```
  INSERT INTO projects (id, column1,column4, column6, column7)  VALUES (2, 'OK','x',1, SYSDATE);
-- 1 row inserted.
```

Note *never* use a *trigger* if a simple CHECK constraint is sufficient.

Comment: Hm, that's not how I understood the question. The OP said that we should "... allow Column7 only to be changed to a different value if columns 4 and 6 are NOT NULL." It is about **updating** COLUMN7 only if columns 4 and 6 are NOT NULL. I tested what you suggested and ... well, it *failed*. (Yes, I know - you used columns 4 and 5, but I took care about it).

Comment: I 'm delighted and impressed with your engagement on this site - not only providing answers, but also reacting on the answers of other subjects @Littlefoot , which I either due to lack of time or intentionally ignore.  Anyway the *understanding* is a great stuff because it is not confined. I *understood* contrary to your interpretation this as the core point: `the column7 must be NULL if columns 4 or 6 are NULL, respectively only can be NOT NULL if columns 4 AND 6 are NOT NULL`  which I must admit makes more sense to me than the previous “statements” about *updating*.

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right. It would be much better if the OP didn't post contradictory information. I sincerely hope they'll find something useful in what we wrote (maybe even *combine* both options ... can't tell). Nice hat, BTW :)

Comment: This solved my problem. I wanted to thank you guys. Once for pointing out how I can improve my interaction on this site and once for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You are welcome, and also free to *upvote / accept* that is the usual way of saing *thanks* on SO;) @f10aty

Answer (score 0):

That's task for a trigger, I'd say.

Simplified table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE projects
  2  (
  3     id        INTEGER CONSTRAINT projpk PRIMARY KEY,
  4     column1   VARCHAR2 (30),
  5     column2   VARCHAR2 (10),
  6     column3   INTEGER,
  7     column4   VARCHAR2 (20),
  8     column5   INTEGER,
  9     column6   INTEGER,
 10     column7   DATE
 11  );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ch7
  2     BEFORE UPDATE
  3     ON projects
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     IF :old.column7 <> :new.column7
  7     THEN
  8        IF     :new.column4 IS NULL
  9           AND :new.column6 IS NULL
 10        THEN
 11           NULL;
 12        ELSE
 13           raise_application_error (
 14              -20000,
 15              'Col 7 can not be changed because cols 4 and 6 are not empty');
 16        END IF;
 17     END IF;
 18  END;
 19  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO projects (id, column1, column7)
  2       VALUES (1, 'test', SYSDATE);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> UPDATE projects
  2     SET column7 = SYSDATE + 1
  3   WHERE id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL>
SQL> UPDATE projects
  2     SET column4 = 'not empty'
  3   WHERE id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL>
SQL> UPDATE projects
  2     SET column7 = SYSDATE + 2
  3   WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE projects
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Col 7 can not be changed because cols
4 and 6 are not empty
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_CH7", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
'SCOTT.TRG_CH7'


SQL>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the optimal solution. But thanks for your effort :)